# undefined function Generating Functions

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I am trying to generate 100 functions using metaprogramming in Elixir

I want the function to return a value that is computed during compile time

```
def func(0) do
  "you have 0 chances"
end

def func(1) do
  "you have 1 chances"
end

...

def func(100) do
  "you have 100 chances"
end
```

My first attempt was

```
0..100 |> Enum.each fn val ->
    def func(unquote(val)) do
        val_string = to_string(unquote(val))
        "you have " <> val_string <> " chances"
    end
end
```

But I have reason to believe that this just returns 100 functions that aren't evaluated during compile time.

Finally I tried this

```
0..100 |> Enum.each fn vol ->
  defmacro func(unquote(vol) = vol) do
    quote do
      "you have " <>  unquote(vol) <> " chances" |> unquote
    end
  end
end
```

but when I require the file and I call func(1) in iex I get

```
** (CompileError) iex:2: undefined function func/1
```

Is my defmacro logic correct in the first place? Any idea what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First, just in case, you can acheive the same thing with a regular function, without metaprogramming:

```elixir
def func(num) when num in 0..100 do
  "you have #{num} chances"
end
```

But if you are practising metaprogramming, remember that you need to `unquote` any of the compile-time values:

```elixir
for i <- 0..100 do
  def func(unquote(i)) do
    unquote("you have #{i} chances")
  end
end
```

Comment: In second example one can use `unquote("You have #{i} chances")` to generate string in compile time instead of run-time. And in  first example `when num in 0..100` is IMHO clearer.

Comment: Thanks @Hauleth, interesting the range even compiles to the same guard: `is_integer(num) and (num >= 0 and num <= 100)`. Agree it's clearer and updated the answer for both cases.

Comment: I believe you slightly misunderstood the requirement and the code example in the question is contrived. AFAIU, the question is “How to evaluate the block content in compile time.” Please see my answer.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, `num in 0..100` does require you to know that ranges are discrete, i.e. using non-integers like `5.5 in 0..100` is `false`. Writing the long way is explicit and requires less knowledge of how ranges work. So which is clearer is not clean-cut, IMO. As for what the requirement was, I guess we won't know unless the OP comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I properly understand the requirement, you want the *block* of the function to be compiled to somewhat static.

Your first example is almost doing that, save for it does not expand the block itself, because of how [`Kernel.def/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#def/2) macro [expands](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.12.2/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L4706-L4715).

---

What you should understand, is how [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) compiler actually works. It starts with expanding all the macros deep-first, until there is nothing to expand. Then the resulting AST gets compiled. `def/2` returns a quoted expression, hence there is nothing more to expand, and the whole block’s AST is compiled. The block content is a runtime beast, which makes it possible to e. g. call `System.get_env/1` from there and retrieve the runtime environment.

If your example is not contrived, you might go with explicit precompilation of the block content during compilation stage:

```elixir
0..100 |> Enum.each fn val ->
  val_string = to_string(val)
  block = "you have " <> val_string <> " chances"
  def func(unquote(val)), do: unquote(block)
end
```

If your example is contrived, and actually there is more complex stuff within *block*, and you want only some parts of it to be precompiled, here is where you should clearly see why the compiler failed to perform what you actually wanted: one should prepare (read: compile) all the static parts upfront.

---

Macros, as I said above, are expanded during the compilation stage. That said, you might use macro there for convenience.

```elixir
0..100 |> Enum.each fn val ->
  defmacro func(unquote(val) = val) do
    quote bind_quoted: [val: val] do
      "you have #{val} chances"
    end
  end
end
```

Then there won’t be any trail of `func` in the resulting code whatsoever. In place of calls to `func/1` the resulting AST (the binary `"you have 42 chances"`) will be injected.